Merging two commands for left and right alignment
I have the following two commands.  Have can I conveniently merge the two into a single command ?
The unstarred version clears previously set keys, whereas the starred will keep the values.  And using m to pass the key-value pairs.
\keys_define:nn { kvi_adrs }
  {
    dwlg .tl_set:N = \dwlg_adrs,
    dwlg .initial:n = ,
    %dwlg .default:n = ,
    dwlg .value_required:n = false,
    dwlg .usage = general,

    hmlt .tl_set:N = \hmlt_adrs,
    hmlt .initial:n = ,
    %hmlt .default:n = ,
    hmlt .value_required:n = false,
    hmlt .usage = general,
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \imprint_adrs:
  {
    \begin {tabular} { @{} l@{} }
      \tl_if_blank:VF \dwlg_adrs
        { \tl_use:N \dwlg_adrs \\ }

      \tl_if_blank:VF \hmlt_adrs
        { \tl_use:N \hmlt_adrs \\ }

    \end {tabular}
  }

\NewDocumentCommand {\ladrs} { s m }
  {
    \bool_if:NF {#1}
      { \keys_set:nn {kvi_adrs} { dwlg = , hmlt = , } }

    \keys_set:nn {kvi_adrs} {#2}

    \begin {flushleft} \imprint_adrs: \end {flushleft}

  }

\NewDocumentCommand {\radrs} { s m }
  {
    \bool_if:NF {#1}
      { \keys_set:nn {kvi_adrs} { dwlg = , hmlt = , } }

    \keys_set:nn {kvi_adrs} {#2}

    \begin {flushright} \imprint_adrs: \end {flushright}

  }


your question is far from clear. :N arguments should be a single token not a brace group so it should be  \bool_if:NF  #1 but it seems the commands are the same apart from using flushleft or flushright so make a single align key that takes left or right and use that to construct the alignment. is that what you mean by "merge"

Yes, the only difference is one uses flushleft whilst the other flushright.

I thought I can enclose #1 with {}, but you say that makes a group.  I assumed that arguments to commands can always be enclosed by {} without implying grouping.

no the {} do not make a group but they make a brace delimited argument that would be :n arguments of type :N are explicitly for single unbraced tokens.

I do not understand.  You mentioned a :N arguments should be a single token not a brace group so it should be  \bool_if:NF #1

Should it be \bool_if:nF {#1} ?  Cannot see why using {} make a difference and when not.

Would the align key be included in kvi_adrs ?

There are command rules requiring unbraced arguments.  This is new to me.

@DavidCarlisle What would one generally use for my case ? \bool_if:nF {#1} or \bool_if:NF #1 ?

Somewhere you have been shown expl3 conventions like \bool_if:NF any such documentation will explain what the characters after the : stand for it is literally the first thing explained in the the main L3 documentation, texdoc interface3 look at the first item on page 2. N and n These mean no manipulation, of a single token for N and of a set of tokens given in braces for n.

https://ctan.net/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf is not being found from the website

you have given no indication of the intended use, it would affect what you pass in as the first argument in the command you are defining

you can use https://texdoc.org/serve/interface3/0  but you should have the file installed locally and accessed via texdoc

It is just to decide whether it is a starred or unstarred version.  Although I had read it, I did not fully understand the implications you described now. Meaning that {#1} would still mean multiple tokens even if only one argument is passed.

oh it's an s  I'd use \IfBooleanF {#1}{...}% sse texdoc usrguide  page 9 (or, I notice, egreg's answer below)

Te be fully correct when testing just a single argument for false value, :N would be explicit.  Is it possible to pass multiple values with :n? In such multiple value case, what would the \bool_if:nF do ?

sorry I can't guess what you mean bool_if tests a boolean expression, you can give it an expression made up of and and or of several values but you can't give it a list of multiple values

When would use of \bool_if:nF be necessary over \bool_if:NF is a clearer question.  It is the set of tokens that makes me wonder about their use.

:N would be a variable of type boolean, and :n is a boolean expression which can use && for and and || for or so the first would be something like \l_foo_bool the latter would be something like (from the manual) { \cs_if_free_p:N \l_tmpz_tl || \cs_if_free_p:N \g_tmpz_tl }

Makes sense. I find that the use of \IfBooleanF for starred versions when using \NewDocumentCommand (which is expl3) rather than the usual \bool_if:NF or  \bool_if:nF quite annoying.  Many things doing the same thing, but choosing one over the other as a matter of custom.

\IfBooleanF {#1}{...} is not described in texdoc usrguide page 9.

unless you have a very old latex distribution page 9 has this section

My impression is that you want to avoid code duplication.
Note that \bool_if:NF is wrong in that context. I gave mock definitions for the keys, just to show how to precompile them for use in the non-*-version of the commands.
\NewDocumentCommand {\ladrs} { s m }
 {
  \IfBooleanF {#1} { \l_kvi_adrs_reset_tl }
  \kvi_adrs:nn { left } { #2 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand {\radrs} { s m }
 {
  \IfBooleanF {#1} { \l_kvi_adrs_reset_tl }
  \kvi_adrs:nn { right } { #2 }
 }

\keys_define:nn { kvi_adrs }
 {
  name .tl_set:N = \l_kvi_adrs_name_tl,
  role .tl_set:N = \l_kvi_adrs_role_tl,
  kmpn .tl_set:N = \l_kvi_adrs_kmpn_tl,
  dwlg .tl_set:N = \l_kvi_adrs_dwlg_tl,
  hmlt .tl_set:N = \l_kvi_adrs_hmlt_tl,
  vltw .tl_set:N = \l_kvi_adrs_wltw_tl,
  cbrg .tl_set:N = \l_kvi_adrs_cbrg_tl,
  knty .tl_set:N = \l_kvi_adrs_knty_tl,
  pstc .tl_set:N = \l_kvi_adrs_pstc_tl,
  ktry .tl_set:N = \l_kvi_adrs_ktry_tl,
}

\tl_new:N \l__kvi_adrs_reset_tl

\keys_precompile:nnN { kvi_adrs }
 {
  name = , role = , kmpn = , dwlg = , hmlt = ,
  vltw = , cbrg = , knty = , pstc = , ktry = ,
 } \l__kvi_adrs_reset_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \kvi_adrs:nn
 {
  \keys_set:nn {kvi_adrs} {#2}
  \begin {flush#1} \imprint_adrs: \end {flush#1}
 }


The idea behind \NewDocumentCommand is, in connection with expl3, to absorb arguments and pass them to expl3 functions. The check for arguments of type s or t should be \IfBoolean(TF) (the parentheses denote the possibility of using TF, T or F).
Use \bool_if:N(TF) only in pure expl3 code.

If you want just one command, you need some way to specify whether you want left or right alignment, for instance
\NewDocumentCommand {\adrs} { s m m }
 {
  \IfBooleanF {#1} { \l_kvi_adrs_reset_tl }
  \kvi_adrs:en { \__kvi_adrs_side:n {#2} } {#3}
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \kvi_adrs:nn
 {
  \keys_set:nn {kvi_adrs} {#2}
  \begin {flush#1} \imprint_adrs: \end {flush#1}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \kvi_adrs:nn { e }

\cs_new:Nn \__kvi_adrs_side:n
 {
  \str_case:nnF {#1}
   {
    {l}{left}
    {L}{left}
    {r}{right}
    {R}{right}
    {left}{left}
    {right}{right}
   }
   {left}% default for bad choice
 }

This can be called
\adrs{l}{<keys>}
\adrs{L}{<keys>}
\adrs{r}{<keys>}
\adrs{R}{<keys>}
\adrs{left}{<keys>}
\adrs{right}{<keys>}

or with *-variant, of course.

How does the choice between left and right work?
Suppose you call
\adrs{l}{<keys>}

This will trigger the execution of
\kvi_adrs:en { \__kvi_adrs_side:n {l} } {<keys>}

Now this is where the magic happens: the e argument type means that TeX will perform full expansion of \__kvi_adrs_side:n {l} and then do
\kvi_adrs:en { <result> } {<keys>}

where <result> is what's returned by the full expansion of
\__kvi_adrs_side:n {l}

which becomes
\str_case:nnF {#1}
 {
  {l}{left}
  {L}{left}
  {r}{right}
  {R}{right}
  {left}{left}
  {right}{right}
 }
 {left}% default for bad choice

How does \str_case:nnF work? The first argument is matched in order with the first item in the listed pairs; as soon as a match is found, the second item in the corresponding pair is returned. In the case at hand, left is returned, so the call will be
\kvi_adrs:en { <result> } {<keys>}

that becomes
  \keys_set:nn {kvi_adrs} {<keys>}
  \begin {flushleft} \imprint_adrs: \end {flushleft}

because #1 is replaced by the obtained result.

I would like to use the \bool_if routines.  Aren't \bool_if the new expl3 ones ?

Would like just one command named \adrs.

@Bulldrive 1. In the body of \NewDocumentCommand the function of choice is \IfBooleanTF (or variant thereof). 2. If you want just one command you need to specify whether you want left or right, so you need another argument.

@Bulldrive I added a proposal for the single command.
